# simplify $((p\lor(r\lor q))\land\neg(\neg q\land\neg r)$ using logic laws

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I have to simplify this statement

$((p\lor (r\lor q))\land\neg(\neg q\land\neg r)$ as much as I can the answer is $q\lor r $

and I know the laws and the order in which they should be applied

The first law that should be used is de Morgans however I don't understand the steps and how would the expression look after the execution of each 
Help me understand this it's pretty confusing

Comment: The answer cannot be $p \land r$ : note that the given statement is completely 'symmetric' in terms of $q$ and $r$, and yet in the 'answer' you get a $q$ but not an $r$. So, I can immediately tell somethng is wrong here: either the given statement is not what you say it is, or the answer is not what you day it is (or both). i also note that the given statement misses a parenthesis ... my money would be on you not having written the given statement correctly: can you please check?

Comment: yup my mistake edited it

Comment: Same comment: the answer still contains $r$ but not $q$, but the given is 'symmetric' with regard to $r$ and $q$. Please check your given statement as well.

Comment: the statement is an exact copy directly from my discrete mathematics assignment so not there is nothing wrong with it and it doesn't miss a parenthesis.

Comment: Well, then I can understand you are confused because the answer must be wrong!

Comment: The statement in the title is a conjunction, but in the body of the post it is a disjunction. So which is it? And by the way, the answer can still not be $p \lor r$ for the same reason as stated before.

Comment: okay this post it a mess I know the answer should be q or r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given statement has one more opening parenthesis than closing parenthesis .... but I'll go with:

$(p\lor (r\lor q))\land \neg(\neg q\land\neg r)$

OK, like you said, DeMorgan seems like a good first step:

$(p\lor (r\lor q))\land (\neg\neg q\lor \neg \neg r)$

Two double negations gives:

$(p\lor (r\lor q))\land(q\lor r)$

By Commutation:

$(p\lor ( q \lor r))\land(q \lor r)$

Absorption:

$q \lor r$

Unfortunately, some textbooks do not give you Absorption. If not, you can do:

$(p \lor (q \lor r)) \land (q \lor r)$

Identity:

$(p \lor (q \lor r)) \land (\bot \lor (q \lor r))$

Distribution:

$(p \land \bot) \lor (q \lor r)$

Annihilation:

$\bot \lor (q \lor r)$

Identity:

$q \lor r$

Comment: this is not the statement , this is the statement ( p v(r v p)) v ~(~q ^ ~r)

Comment: @Somebody OK ... next time make sure you write down the right statement in the first place! Anyway, I'll change my Answer accordingly. Give me a sec

Comment: @Somebody Hey, it all makes sense now!

Comment: Yea it does, thank you for your answer. I appreciate the help 

Answer (score 1):

$((p\lor(r\lor q))\land\neg(\neg q\land\neg r)\equiv(p\lor(r\lor q))\land\neg(\neg(q\lor r))\equiv(p\lor(r\lor q))\land(q\lor r)\equiv q\lor r$

---

**explanation:**

$(1)$DeMorgan:
$\neg(q\lor r)\equiv\neg q\land\neg r$ (you have: $\neg q\land\neg r\equiv\neg(q\lor r)$

$(2)$ $\neg(\neg(q\lor r)\equiv q\lor r$

$(3)$ $(p\lor\underbrace{(q\lor r)}_{s})\land\underbrace{(q\lor r)}_{s}\equiv(p\lor s)\land s\equiv s\equiv q\lor r$

Comment: can you list the logic laws you used in the order you used them, please

Comment: I advise you to draw diagrams and analyze each law to get an intuitive insight.

Comment: okay, I understood it but what is the law in the 3rd step called?

Comment: @Somebody, I have no idea how it's called, we don't learn propositional calculus that way at the university. Just draw a diagram or write down the truth table and think.

Comment: I mean I get it no need for explanation but the task is to state the laws you are using at each step

Comment: @Somebody,  I looked up for the word, you have it written in another answer. However, it doesn't say anywhere in your post you have to write it down.

Comment: @Somebody, I hope I helped a bit. You can always write down a part of the proof if you forget sth, like a name, if your teachers insist on that. That should be legitimate.

Comment: you did help, thank you for your answer